# Is it possible to have Wake-up-on-demand with a third party WiFi router?

Tags: macos, mac, macbook, wake-up

Apple on their website describes a new feature in 10.6 - [Mac OS X v10.6: About Wake on Demand](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3774). This functionality lets Time-Capsule or Air-port to wake a Mac from the sleep mode. So here comes my question. Is it possible to enable any third party WiFi router to wake my mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. I can wake up my iMac over wireless using WRT54GL.

Here is my how to:
[link text](http://cahuk.tumblr.com/post/1225435377/wake-on-wireless-mac-and-wrt54gl)

Comment: Welcome to Super User, but please read [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) and [Limit to self-promotion in answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limit-to-self-promotion-in-answers) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any other devices that implement the Bonjour Sleep Proxy feature, but Apple's implementation is open source, and I don't think there's any reason it couldn't be supported by other manufacturers.  There's some discussion [here](http://www.linksysinfo.org/forums/showthread.php?t=64245&page=10#94) about adding it to  Tomato, but it doesn't look like they got it working.